# bootstrap-datetimepicker validations in the jsp

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, smalot-datetimepicker

I am using spring-mvc and bootstrap in my web application. In on of the pages I have 2 fields which are for the user to enter startdate-time and end date-time, this I picked up from bootstrap-datetimepicker.js 
 https://github.com/smalot/bootstrap-datetimepicker

This works fine, but now I need to include validations, that startdate-time is always greater than enddate-time, I am also using jquery.validate.min.js for form validations, but I am not able to compare the 2 timestamps, I tried the below code

```
$.validator.addMethod("budgetgreaterThan", 
          function(value, element, params) {
      alert(value);
      value=value.slice(0,-6);


        if (!/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value))) {
            return new Date(value) >= new Date($(params).val());
        }
        return isNaN(value) && isNaN($(params).val()) 
            || (Number(value) > Number($(params).val())); 
    },'Must be greater than {0}.');

rules:
{
  budgetgreaterThan: '#startdate' 
}

messages:
{
    budgetgreaterThan:"Delivery date and Collect date should be proper"
}
```

the timestamp value here is in this format `"YYYY-MM-DD hhhh:mm:ss"`

Can anyone please tell me how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by making an ajax call and verifying at the backend, I avoided `$.validator.addMethod()` and instead used a `onblur="myFunction()"`

```
<input type="text" id="enddate" name="enddate" onblur="myFunction()">

<script>
function myFunction()
{

  var sdate = $('#startdate').val();
  var edate = $('#enddate').val();

  var totaldate = sdate+"/"+edate;

   $.ajax({
     url: '${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/developer/createinstance/TimeCheck.prm',
     type: 'get',
     data: "totaldate="+totaldate,
     success: function (data1) {
       if(data1 == -1)
       {     
         bootbox.alert("enddate cannot be lesser than start date");
         $('#startdate').val("");
         $('#enddate').val("");
       }
       if(data1 == 0)
       {
         bootbox.alert("date cannot be same");
         $('#startdate').val("");
         $('#enddate').val("");
       }
     }
   });
}
</script>
```

but I am sure there is a better way to implement this, if anyone can give a better solution it will be great.